# Remove ZoomAudioDevice from Audio Devices

Tags: audio, macos

I'm a mac user for years, even a developer, but I cannot remove this audio device from "zoom.us" from my Mac.

[image]

Any ideas appreciated ...

Comment: Why do you want to remove it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It appears the ZoomAudioDevice is now located in `/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/` and is no longer a kext.

To uninstall it, I deleted it with the below command and restarted.

```
sudo rm -r /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/ZoomAudioDevice.driver
```

This is with a new install from May 2019. Perhaps old installs continue using the kext if its already installed. Though, [the readme here](https://github.com/zoom/zoom-sdk-macos/tree/master/Plugins) indicates the .driver file is used on MacOS 10.10 and above.

Comment: This is with a new install from May 2019. Perhaps old installs continue using the kext if its already installed. Though, [the readme here](https://github.com/zoom/zoom-sdk-macos/tree/master/Plugins) indicates the `.driver` file is used on MacOS 10.10 and above.

Comment: Fantastic information Brezza, thanks for that

Comment: This is the correct answer for anyone running Zoom from 2019 or later. For those interested in completely removing all the garbage Zoom leaves behind when you use their uninstaller (like this audio plugin as well as internet plugins and more), I put a script on Github to hopefully help others save some time and rest easier knowing Zoom as been removed from their device completely:
https://github.com/kris-anderson/remove-zoom-macos

Comment: @KrisAnderson this was perfect.

Comment: Any way to just disable this, not completely uninstall? Then I can just reenable it when I need it? Would adding `.` in front of the file name will just disable it?

Answer (score 9):

This is from Zoom.us video conferencing software.

[Here](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/201362983-How-to-uninstall-Zoom-on-a-Mac-?mobile_site=true) is a great explanation. I was wondering the same thing.

From the linked answer:

```
sudo kextunload -b zoom.us.ZoomAudioDevice
sudo rm /System/Library/Extensions/ZoomAudioDevice.kext
```

Answer (score 2):

HISTORIC ANSWER:

See @BrezzaP 's answer for the current solutions, thanks @BrezzaP

---

Ah - answering my own question, it is at

/System/Library/Extensions/ .. search on "zoom"

Phew!

Answer (score 0):

I had to open finder, search for zoom, and then drag the install file and the zoom file to the trash. That worked.